# Python 3 - SQL Result - where to store it

Tags: python, database, multithreading

I'm wrinting a webapp in bottle.
I have a small interface that lets user run sql statements.
Sometimes it takes about 5 seconds until the user get's a result because the DB is quite big and old.

What I want to do is the following:
1.Starte the query in a thread
2.Give the user a response right away and have ajax poll for the result

There is one thing that I'm not sure of....Where do I store the result of the query?
Should I store it in a DB ?
Should I store it in a variable inside my webapp ?

What do you guys think would be best ?

Comment: Store it in a variable is OK. If the query result is pretty big, pickle to file store maybe an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a good use for something like memcached.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. To be honest I don't see the big difference between memcache and storing it in a variable unless you unify the memory of several machines, but I'm not going to do that. Could you explain a little what the advantag woud be?